# Is there a webapp for tracking my sleep patterns/habits?

Tags: webapp-rec

Is there an app that some way can track the times I go to sleep and more importantly log the times at which I (assumably) awake every day?

For instance, install a small script to Ubuntu or a webapp that logs my activity from different accounts and can say that I must have been awake at least at 6 AM day before yesterday even if I didn't take a note.

Or just some app that lets me manually keep a diary over my sleeping schedule?

Comment: Something like this? isleepdiary.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [YawnLog](http://beta.yawnlog.com) but I haven't used it.